# Ruby Logger acting weird and logging informations to diff

Tags: ruby, logging

I'm using ruby logger with my project, I have conf.rb which is something like  :

```
require 'rubygems'

# initiate the logger file 
$LOG = Logger.new("#{$ROOT_PATH}/log/errors.log", 'daily')  
$LOG.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

And in more like a worker I'm using it something like worker1.rb:

```
require "#{$ROOT_PATH}/conf.rb"
$LOG.error "test"
```

Now as for example, as for today i'm supposed to get all the results in **error.log** file but instead i'm getting results at log/errors.log.20130221, log/errors.log.20130221.1, and log/errors.log.20130221.2. The workers running all the time so didn't restart it.

I'm using ruby ruby 1.9.3p0 under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

`Logger#datetime_format` is referencing to the dates within log file(log formatter) not the filename format rotation.

The filename of the rotated files are hardcoded into lib - https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/logger.rb#L645

You can either redefine method, either use rotatelogs

```
Logger.new(IO.popen("/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l file_pattern period", 'a'))
```

The .1, .2 extensions appears because Logger have `shift_size` set by default. Once log file reach that value, logs got rotated, but since it's the same date, logger is adding [numbers](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/logger.rb#L649) to prevent collision
.

Comment: Thanks for your welling to help here, anyways I really don't think the extensions has anything to do with the size rather than more than worker trying to access the same log somehow since it is not related to the size based on my observation, and my main problem is not with the format rather than with that it is supposed to route the logs to error.log since that format supposed to be for the previous date